# Expected value or median of a function defined on sphere with uniform distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, measure-theory

Suppose $S$ is the sphere of radius one. And suppose $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows:
$$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{x_1^2}+\frac{1}{x_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n^2}$$

I am trying to calculate either of these:
$$\int f(\gamma)d\gamma$$ where integrating is with respect to Haar measure over the sphere. Or maybe finding the median of the induced random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f$. I appreciate any help in this direction.

Comment: You can try [n-dimensional spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) to integrate it. Honestly, it's more of a math question and has a little to do with stats. I'd suggest to post it on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Well the truth is I did. Maybe you are right. But the reason I posted this is that $f(\gamma)$ is a random variable in the end that I calculate expected value with respect to.... I wanted to apply Levy's lemma to it :)

Comment: If you want to calculate expected value numerically, then Stats is the right place to ask. In that case you can use Monte Carlo methods to sample points on an n-sphere. This is a good way to check your analytical calculations.

Comment: Numerical calculations are quite promising but I cannot get anywhere else analytically :|

Comment: It looks like the integral (for n > 1) is divergent, thus the expectation doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates):

$$
x_k = \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \sin(\phi_j) \cos(\phi_k) \\
J = \prod_{j=1}^{n-2} \sin^{n-1-j}(\phi_j)
$$

I omitted $r$ because we'll be considering sphere of unit radius. Thus

$$
\int f d S
 = 2^n \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \dots \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \Bigl( \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \sin^{-2}(\phi_j) \cos^{-2}(\phi_k) \Bigr) \prod_{j=1}^{n-2} \sin^{n-1-j}(\phi_j) d \phi_1 \dots d \phi_n \\
 = 2^n \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \dots \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \sin^{-2}(\phi_j) \cos^{-2}(\phi_k) \prod_{j=1}^{n-2} \sin^{n-1-j}(\phi_j) d \phi_1 \dots d \phi_n
$$

The last equation looks frightening, but it's just a product on $n$ integrals of sinuses and cosinuses raised to some power. And some of them are of particular interest.

Consider $\phi_{n-1}$ for $k = n$. Corresponding integral is

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{-2}(\phi_{n-1}) d\phi_{n-1}
$$

This integral is divergent. Clearly, the whole sum thus is unbounded.

Thus the expectation does not exist.

Comment: This is the easy part!  (It doesn't really require spherical coordinates to be answered, either.)  The hard part of the question is--what is the median of $f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$?  *That* calculation might benefit from the use of spherical coordinates.